# While loop only fetching last row

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to total up some numbers from this table, and for some reason it's only giving me the last row.  The data is there when I checked the table manually using the SQL server studio.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.timesheets";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $totalVacation = $row['sunV1']+$row['sunV2'];
}
```

Comment: Use `$totalVacation += $row['sunV1']+$row['sunV2'];` You are now over-writing the previous value and after loop, it is only the last summation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resetting the value on every iteration, overwriting what the variable had in it on the previous iteration:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $totalVacation = $row['sunV1']+$row['sunV2'];
}
```

You want to continually add up the values. I.e., the new value is the old value plus the current value:

```
$totalVacation = 0;
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $totalVacation = $totalVacation + $row['sunV1']+$row['sunV2'];
}
```

Or, the shorthand syntax:

```
$totalVacation = 0;
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $totalVacation += $row['sunV1']+$row['sunV2'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't overwrite $totalVacation in the loop, sum up: `$totalVacation += $row['sunV1']+$row['sunV2'];`.

You need to init the variable `$totalVacation` above the while(...) statement, normaly done with `$totalVacation = 0;`.